# Warning "ORDER BY is ignored in subqueries without LIMIT" in R sparklyr

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr

### Issue

Sparklyr script output is filled with the same warning message (over and over again) :

*"ORDER BY is ignored in subqueries without LIMIT
Do you need to move arrange() later in the pipeline or use window_order() instead?"*

I have the same issue everywhere (local, databricks, jupyter, etc.)

I don't know exactly what is causing the warning but it appears generally when I use dplyr::group_by() with dplyr::arrange().

### Reproducible example

```
library("dplyr"); library("sparklyr") 
spark_version <- "3.1.3"
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", version = spark_version)

# --- coping mtcars data into spark for the example
sdf_mtcars = sdf_copy_to(sc = sc, x = mtcars, name = "sdf_mtcars")

# --- example generating the warning message (twice)
# note : I had to use mutate() twice to make the warning appear
# the warning does not appear in this simple example if only one of the two columns cum_mpg or max_mpg is created
example_mtcars = sdf_mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  arrange(mpg, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(cum_mpg = cumsum(mpg)) %>%
  mutate(max_mpg = cummax(mpg)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  sdf_collect()
```

Warning messages in R :

> 1: ORDER BY is ignored in subqueries without LIMIT
> ℹ Do you need to move arrange() later in the pipeline or use window_order() instead?

> 2: ORDER BY is ignored in subqueries without LIMIT
> ℹ Do you need to move arrange() later in the pipeline or use window_order() instead?

In this simple example the warnings appears twice but in my code it can appear up to 50 times.
The output is not really readable.

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried using `dbplyr::window_order` but still have the issue. I think it's a dbplyr issue. If I have time I will make a report there, if you can make it first I will support you : https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/issues